# Random behavior of setTimeout on console. How to get counts in order and reason for this behavior?

Tags: javascript, events, queue

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  function timer(j) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert(j);
    }, 1000);
  }
  timer(i);
};
```

This code is generating random outcomes of count. Why is this behavior and what can I do to get proper ordered counts.

Comment: Describe the output of the code. "Random" doesn't help and is not accurate. Does it ever output `10`? I don't think so.

Comment: There's nothing random, you set `var i = 0; i < 5;` Only these numbers will show.

Comment: @sr9yar Depending on the browser, it *might* be a random number from 0 to 4.

Comment: btw, alert !== console

Comment: @CertainPerformance, ok then, but this is still not a "random outcome" :), more like random execution time, since I expect all those numbers, but only  the order they show is scrambled.

Answer (score 2):

When the script runs, the `for` loop is running, and you are initializing 5 `setTimeout`s all at once, each of which times out after 1000 milliseconds. Because they're all set to run at the same time, and since `setTimeout` isn't even millisecond-precise, the timeout order won't be predictable. Another potential confounding factor is that `alert` *blocks*.

As the comments below illustrate, the `setTimeout`s *may* happen to run in the order they were set, but it's not guaranteed - behavior may differ across browsers. So, if you want to make sure they run in the order they were set, add a few milliseconds for each iteration:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  function timer(j) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(j);
    }, 1000 + (j * 12));
  }
  timer(i);
}
```

`alert` version:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  function timer(j) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert(j);
    }, 1000 + (j * 12));
  }
  timer(i);
}
```

Comment: Not for me, when I run it here on stack snippets or on JSFiddle.

Comment: @NinaScholz: What exactly do you mean by "in sync"?

Comment: @brk: It may well depend on browser and operating system. For me (Windows, Chrome) the alerts appeared in an unpredictable order.

Comment: It's not in sync for me on Chrome 66.0.3359.181, nor on Opera 53

Comment: Here is a link https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-d4dcen, console.log is logging output in order, on changing to alert the order is not maintained

Comment: you can run the code on chrome console. Each time you'll get different results.

Comment: @brk: Okay, so the original code in the question does *not* show it in order? I thought you meant it did...

Answer (score 0):

You're *starting* five timers, in very quick succession, and all with the same delay. I suspect that if you looked at the internal details of when the timers are intended to fire, they'd all have the exact same target time, unless the system clock happens to "tick" between timer instantiations.

There's no strict ordering of timers that are meant to fire at effectively the same time. All you're seeing is several timers firing at roughly the same time, in no particular order. It's like setting off 5 fireworks at the same time, each with the same fuse length - they'll all go off at "about" the same time, but there's no guarantee that the one you lit first will ignite first. This is just the nature of timers, and it's best not to fight it.

If you want to do lots of things all at the same time in the future, I suggest you start a single timer that executes all the desired operations when it fires.

If you really, really need additional ordering but for everything to fire at "basically the same time", you could make each timer keep a reference to the "previous" timer, and wait for that timer to finish first. It would be pretty ugly though, and I'd at least try to avoid requiring it. Either the events are meant to be independent, in which case the ordering doesn't matter, or they're interdependent, in which case you should probably be scheduling them differently.

Comment: This is not what he is asking for

Comment: @Milind: The OP asked why it's giving output in an unpredcitable order - and I've explained that. I've then explained that trying to *make* it predictable isn't a good idea. What do you believe the OP is asking about that I haven't addressed?

Answer (score 0):

> Random behavior of setTimeout on console, ...and reason for this
>   behavior?

As mentioned already, the order of execution for each `setTimeout` is not guaranteed, and that is because they run independently of each other, based on a given delay and not in their initiated order, and can therefore fire randomly.

> How to get counts in order...?

Again as mentioned, a minor change to the delay could be one solution, still, that is not guaranteed either, for the same reason, though with a big enough delay difference it most likely will.

---

Assuming you want to run an amount of functions, with a delay and in a certain *"guaranteed"* order, here is one solution, where one store the functions in an array, and then execute them 1-by-1.

Stack snippet - with alert

```js
var fn_arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  fn_arr.push( function() { alert(i) } )  
};

setTimeout(function() {
  fn_arr.forEach( (fn) => fn() )
}, 1000);
```

Stack snippet - with console

```js
var fn_arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  fn_arr.push( function() { console.log(i) } )  
};

setTimeout(function() {
  fn_arr.forEach( (fn) => fn() )
}, 1000);
```